# Can I scrape off compounds from normal TLC like in prep TLC for MS analysis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chromatography

As far as I know, the limit of detection of mass spectrometry is very low compared to other analysis. In principle, so I think I can scrape off some compounds from normal TLC plate after development like in prep TLC, filter with appropriate solvent, and get the filtrate. But I have never seen this application. I think there are some reasons for which one can't carry out it, but can't occur to definite reason.

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: @Waylander Oh it is possible. Thank you.

Comment: I might well be tempted to run a line of product mixture up the plate instead of a single spot so that a greater amount of material is harvested